# Can I ensure an installed application only runs when I open it?

Tags: settings, background-process

That is, I want to ensure it consumes no system resources (data, RAM and CPU) unless I open it.

Intuitively, if I block all notifications from an app, this might happen. But then again, it might not.

Does it? If not, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: just turn off all notifications. third parties can control the application with notifications..

Comment: [Disable autostart on boot and restrict background execution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526)

Answer (score 2):

So you want to ensure that certain apps do not start themselves automatically. There are several apps available to [control auto-start behavior](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_autostart#group_847). The currently best ranked app is **Brevent** – available [in the Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.piebridge.brevent) as well as [in my F-Droid repo](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/me.piebridge.brevent). Other than most other apps, this app does not require root to do its job.

Ensuring the app doesn't start unless you tell it to also makes sure it does not consume any resources (except for space on storage) unless you explicitly run it.

Comment: After I ran the app and closed it, does it stay closed? (By close I mean click the square icon and swap it)

Comment: A clear "maybe" is the answer. Depends on the app. That's why those "auto-start-controllers" exist: some apps start on certain events. Most obvious: even if you close the dialer, it will automatically start itself on an incoming call. Other apps might get started on other events, such as headset connected, network changed, SD card mounted …